# PROTO nodes (Current Project) does not exist

Tags: webots

I am currently trying to add a PROTO that is in my project file to an existing world. However, when I try to add a new node, it does not display the "PROTO nodes (Current Project)" section. It only shows:
_ Base nodes

- PROTO nodes (Current world files)
- PROTO nodes (Webots Projects)

So I can't access my PROTO file.
What should I do ?

Thank you

I tried moving my PROTO file from the protos folder to the world folder. Didn't work. Tried creating a new project and starting from scratch. Didn't work.
I am new to Webots so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: It could be that your proto file is invalid. Can you share it here?